# How can I identify a low flying plane at night over Bangalore?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I often see a low flying plane circling over south Bangalore around 00:30-01:00. It circles at least twice and it's not very big, mostly the size of a private jet.

How can I go about identifying it?

Comment: Snap a photo and post it here!
Or maybe go look at flightaware.com the next time you see it!

Comment: A night photo?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Nov 12 at about 1845 UTC, which would be about 1215 local on Nov. 13, a Vistara A320, reg. [VT-TTM](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/VTTTM/history/20171112/1849Z/VOBL/VOBL), took off from BLR and did several touch-and-go’s at VOBG then returned to BLR.

On Nov. 10, around the same time, another Vistara A320, reg. [VT-HYD](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/vt-hyd#f7dcd54), did the same thing. Taking off from BLR, doing touch-and-go’s at VOBG before returning to BLR.

According to [this article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/bengaluru/Private-airlines-training-pilots-at-HAL-airport/articleshow/50352270.cms) @pondlife found, VOBG airport is open for pilot training.

Comment: @mins It’s clearly touch-and-go’s at VOBG runway 27. Why T&G’s in an A320 in the middle of the night? I have no clue.

Comment: @mins I think pondlife figured it out. See edits

Comment: I was hoping this to be something slightly more exciting like some secret electronic surveillance research program etc :D ... many thanks for your response.

Comment: Lol! Sorry to burst your bubble :P

Comment: so I did track it on flightaware this time (0119 AM IST) it took a couple of minutes (~10) to circle twice. It should be IAD9109, but I couldn't get more details probably its Indian airlines(Air India) this time, my google fu didn't work.

Comment: @amritanshu You said in your question it looked like a small jet. Likely there are private aircraft taking advantage of the training opportunity too. Depending on their xponder type they might not track on FR24.

Comment: https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/IAD9109 this was it! the details were not available last night.

Answer (score 1):

An ADS-B receiver is the best way to identify an aircraft flying overhead, in most cases. This can be built from about $50 USD, but may be more.

Put simply, you would need

1. A USB SDR receiver
2. An Antenna
3. A computer to connect the reciever to, and run software on
4. Decoding software (at a minimum, [dump1090](https://github.com/flightaware/dump1090)

Instructions on specifics can be found here: https://www.adsbexchange.com/how-to-feed/adsbx-custom-pi-image/

The Raspberry Pi can be replaced by any Linux computer, really.

Comment: This is the meta answer :)... Pretty cool. Many thanks!

Comment: SO is about giving the guy a fish and teaching him how to fish. :o)